# pointer to string and char catch 22

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I'm studying on pointers and I'm stuck when I see `char *p[10]`. Because something is misunderstood. Can someone explain step-by-step and blow-by-blow why my logic is wrong and what the mistakes are and where did I think wrong and how should I think. Because I want to learn exactly. Also what about `int *p[10];` ? **Besides, for example x is a pointer to char but just char not chars. But how come `char *x = "possible";`**

[image]

I think above one should be right but, I have seen for `char *name[] = { "no month","jan","feb" };` I am really confused.

[image]

Comment: Note that you write `/0` instead of `\0`.

Comment: There is no `string` in C. If you mean something like `typedef char *string;`: Do not! This obfuscates the pointer and is an open door for bugs.

Comment: I know no string class in C just I wonder the logics. @Olaf

Comment: I think your are confusing `char p[10]` and `char *p[10]`. Your pic on the left is the former.

Comment: C also has no classes. Are you aware that both are deemed different languages? The same syntax does not make two languages identical. For C and C++, there are quite some different semantics.

Comment: x is a pointer to char but just char not chars. But how come `char *x = "possible";` @1nflktd

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]. `string` is not defined, so far (also not in C++)

Comment: @newbie see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c

Answer (score 4):

Your `char *p[10]` diagram shows an array where each element points to a character.
You could construct it like this:

```
char f = 'f';
char i = 'i';
char l1 = 'l';
char l2 = 'l';
char a1 = 'a';
char r1 = 'r';
char r2 = 'r';
char a2 = 'a';
char y = 'y';
char nul = '\0';
char *p[10] = { &f, &i, &l1, &l2, &a1, &r1, &r2, &a2, &y, &nul };
```

This is very different from the array

```
char p[10] = {'f', 'i', 'l', 'l', 'a', 'r', 'r', 'a', 'y', '\0'};
```

or

```
char p[10] = "fillarray";
```

which are arrays of characters, not pointers.

A pointer can equally well point to the first element of an array, as you've probably seen in constructions like

```
const char *p = "fillarray";
```

where `p` holds the address of the first element of an array defined by the literal.

This works because an array can *decay* into a pointer to its first element.

The same thing happens if you make an array of pointers:

```
/* Each element is a pointer to the first element of the corresponding string in the initialiser. */
const char *name[] = { "no month","jan","feb" };
```

You would get the same results with

```
const char* name[3];
name[0] = "no month";
name[1] = "jan";
name[2] = "feb";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char c = 'a';
```

Here, `c` is a char, typically a single byte of [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoded data.

```
char* ptr = &c;
```

`ptr` is a `char` pointer. In C, all it does is point to a memory location and doesn't make any guarantees about what is at that location. You could use a `char*` to pass a char to a function to allow the function to allow the function to make changes to that `char` (pass by reference).

A common C **convention** is for a `char*` to point to a memory location where several characters are stored in sequence followed by the null character `\0`. This convention is called a C string:

```
 char const* cstr = "hello";
```

`cstr` points to a block of memory 6 bytes long, ending with a null character. The data itself cannot be modified, though the pointer can be changed to point to something else.

An array of `char`s looks similar, but behaves slightly differently.

```
 char arr[] = "hello";
```

Here `arr` IS a memory block of 6 `char`s. Since `arr` represents the memory itself, it cannot be changed to point to another location. The data can be modified though.

Now,

```
char const* name[] = { "Jan", " Feb"..., "Dec"};
```

is an array of pointer to characters.
`name` is a block of memory, each containing a pointer to a null-terminated string.

In the diagram, I think `string*` was accidentally used instead of `char*`. The difference between the left and the right, is not a technical difference really, but a difference in the way a `char*` is used. On the left each `char*` points to a single character, whereas in the one on the right, each `char*` points to a null-terminated block of characters.

Answer (score 1):

Both are right.

A pointer in C or C++ may point either to a single item (a single `char`) or to the first in an array of items (`char[]`).
So a `char *p[10];` definition may point to 10 single characters or 10 arrays (i.e. 10 strings).

Comment: "C and C++ don't distinguish between a pointer to a single item (a single char) and a pointer to an array" – that's wrong. A pointer-to-array is very different from a pointer-to-non-array. The objects that don't have different types are a pointer to single object and a pointer to the first element of an array of one or more objects.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, I think what I wrote is close enough and simple enough, since arrays decay to a pointer to the first element, and after this has happened there's really no distinction between the result of this decay and a pointer to a single element. Can you phrase this more accurately, while keeping it simple?

Answer (score 1):

Let’s go back to basics.

First, char *p is simply a pointer.  p contains nothing more than a memory address.  That memory address can point to anything, anywhere.  By convention, we have always used NULL (or, I hate this method, assigning it to zero – yeah, they are the same “thing”, but NULL has traditionally been used in conjunction with pointers, so when you’re eyes flit across the code, you see NULL – you think “pointer”).

Anyway, that memory address being pointed to can contain anything.  So, to use within the language, we type it, in this case it is a pointer to a character (char *p).  This can be overridden by type casting, but that’s for a later time.

Second, we know anytime we see  p[10], that we are dealing with an array.  Again, the array can be an array of characters, an array of ints, etc. – but it’s still an array.

Your example: char *p[10], is then nothing more than an array of 10 character pointers.  Nothing more, nothing less.  Your problem comes in because you are trying to force the “string” concept onto this.  There ain’t no strings in C.  There ain’t no objects in C.  The concept of a NULL-terminated string can most certainly be used. But a “string” in C is nothing more than an array of characters, terminated by a NULL (or, if you use some of the appropriate functions, you can use a specific number of characters – strncpy instead of strcpy, etc.).  But, for all its appearance, and apparent use, there are no strings in C.  They are nothing more than arrays of characters, with a few supporting functions that happen to stop going through the array when a NULL is encountered.

So – char a[10] – is simply an array of characters that is 10 characters long.  You can fill it with any characters you wish.  If one of those is the NULL character, then that terminates what is typically called a “C-style string”.  There are functions that support this type of character array (i.e. “string”), but it is still a use of a character array.

Your confusion comes in because you are trying to mix C++ string objects, and forcing that concept onto C arrays of characters.  As ugoren noted – your examples are both correct – because you are dealing with arrays of character pointers, NOT strings.  Again, putting a NULL somewhere in that character array is happily supported by several C functions that give you the ability to work with a “string-like” concept – but they are not truly strings.  Unless of course, you want to phrase it that a string is nothing more than one character following another – an array.